# Программный реконнект к сети (WP)

Tags: c#, windows-10-mobile

Есть ли возможность программно спровоцировать переподключение к сети оператора в Windows Phone 10?

Проблему целиком описывать не буду, слишком долго, но кратко перескажу. Beeline не предоставляет "ночной безлимитный" трафик если не переподключиться в час ночи. Вставть я, само собой, не хочу. Искал программы - ни чего не нашел. Решил сам написать, но что-то я не могу найти необходимый API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой возможности нет. Windows Phone (а вслед за ним и Windows 10 Mobile) предоставляет весьма ограниченный API в плане различных системных вызовов. Максимум что можно сделать -- это написать приложение, которое в час ночи будет вываливать напоминалку и предлагать переподключиться (см. [`ConnectionSettingsTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh394011(v=vs.105).aspx)).